# Putting node.js itself as a dev dependency in a JavaScript based project

Tags: node.js, npm

It's possible to put node.js itself as a **dev-dependency** in a node based project by including it in the package.json as in

```
npm install --save-dev node@12.7
```

In which case apparently all the node based tools like eslint or babel etc will use that version of node installed in `<project_root>/node_modules/.bin`

Here's an example `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test-node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node -v",
    "build": "node build.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "node": "12.7.0"
  }
}
```

Testing it seems to work

```
$ npm install
$ echo "console.log(process.version)" > build.js
$ npm test

> test-node@1.0.0 test /Users/gregg/temp/test-node
> node -v

v12.7.0

$ npm run build

> test-node@1.0.0 build /Users/gregg/temp/test-node
> node build.js

v12.7.0

$ node -v
v12.6.0
```

You can see I have node 12.6 installed in my normal path but the commands above used node 12.7.

This seems like it has a a clear advantage of using an exact known to work version of node with a particular project's dev environment.

Are there any concrete objective reasons to avoid this?

Of the top of my head

1. It makes the dependencies bigger. Node is about 18meg download

   Whether bigger is worse though is a matter of opinion so that's really just an observation, not a reason to avoid.
2. It's one more dependency to update

   That again seems like just an opinion. All dependencies have versions. Arguing that any dependency shouldn't be versioned is a path down saying that all dependencies shouldn't be versioned.

That's really all I can think of. Is there some objective objections like "if you do that X will break because Y"?

Again, I'm not looking for opinions. I'm looking for concrete objective reasons to not do it. One project needs node 8, another needs node 11. Sure setting environment variables or paths can solve that as well but those require vigilance, work, and or extra knowledge. Forget and you get error messages which you have to track down. It also requires more documentation or more knowledge where as putting the required node version in the project itself means it just works.

Also, just to reiterate, this is a **dev-dependency** so only the dependencies needed to run the tools that generate a library, a distribution, or run tests. Of course it would be objectively bad in most cases to include it as a **non-dev** dependency.

note: some will suggest using [`engines`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines). 
engines is an orthogonal setting. It's saying what version of node is need to run your library, not what version of node is needed to build your library or run your tests. In other words, `engines` is a dependecy setting not a **DEV** dependency setting.

note 2: Some will suggesting using `nvm` but that is objectively worse.

In all node based projects, to do development you have to run `npm install`.

By adding `node` directly as a dependency no extra knowledge is needed. Once you've typed `npm install` you're ready to work. Without adding it the new developer has to go google "how to deal with multiple node versions" which is different across platforms. Why make it harder for them and require extra knowledge when adding the dev dependency makes it just work.

Further, nvm is tedious. Consider 2 projects that need different versions of node. With the solution above the workflow is

```
cd projectThatNeedsNode8
npm run build
npm test
cd projectThatNeedsNode12
npm run build
npm test
```

With an nvm based solution it's almost guaranteed to be this workflow

```
cd projectThatNeedsNode8
npm run build
# error, need node 8
nvm use 8
npm run build
npm test
cd projectThatNeedsNode12
npm run build
# error, need node 12
nvm use 12
npm run build
npm test
```

Except that a clear error you need another version of node is probably less than 10% likely. The error will more likely be some stack dump or line number and no indication that the real problem is the wrong version of node.

To put it another way, if adding node directly as a **dev** dependency was the standard way to set **dev** dependencies than `nvm` would likely not exist.

Yes apparently there are more obscure hacks you can add so that nvm is run every time you switch directories. That's still not an objective reason not to just list node as dev dependency.

Comment: Use [engines](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines), not a dependency.

Comment: Why? Using `engines` doesn't solve any issues except to give you an error telling you you have to deal with dependency hell manually.

Comment: What issues *are* you trying to solve? You can use tools like NVM to manage Node versions locally, if that's what the problem is.

Comment: To who ever voted as "too broad", how is this too broad? It's asking a very specific question about a very specific topic. There aren't likely to be 100s of answers in fact it's likely there are at most 1 or 2 for this very specific topic. Either there are 1 or 2 objective reasons or there are 0. Nothing broad about this question whatsoever.

Comment: Engines gives you the "clear error" you're after. Plenty of tooling (I've used direnv) can make NVM as simple as cd. Don't confuse your opinion with "objectively".

Comment: Engine is a dependency not a **dev** dependency. I might need node 12 to run babel 18 to generate a library that works with node 2.  Engine documents the library works with node 2. It does not document that the build itself requires node 12. As for nvm, don't confuse dogma for objective better practices. Either you can spell out objectively why nvm is better or your just following dogma